# PHP - Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::statement()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, authentication

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDO::statement() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/includes/functions.inc.php:13 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/login.php(16): canilogin('test@test.be', 'azertyui') #1 {main} thrown in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Snapshot/includes/functions.inc.php on line 13
```

Anyone knows how I can aroudn this problem? This is a login form, I've created an register form which works and saves the given input into an DB, the pw is saved as hashed as folowing `$hash = password_hash($password,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);`

Now I'm trying to create a login which doesn't seem to work at all after submitting it throws the error above then. Anyone can see what I did wrong? I'm working with OOP in mind.

**Login.php:**

```
<?php 

include_once("includes/functions.inc.php");

// get username and password from $_POST
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $username = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];





// check if a user can login (function)

if(canilogin($username, $password)){
    session_start();
  $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;

//    setcookie("login", $cookieval, time()+60*60*24*7); //1 week


    header('Location: index.php');
}
else{
    $error = true;
   // if no -> $error tonen
}

}



?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"

<body class="login">
    <div class="grid container_login">
        <div class="login_grid">

            <form class="form_login" action="" method="post">


                <?php if( isset($error) ): ?>
                <div class="form__error">
                    <p>
                        Sorry, we can't log you in with that email address and password. Can you try again?
                    </p>
                </div>
                <?php endif;?>

                <div>
                    <label for="email">EMAIL</label><br/>
                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Lucasdebelder@snapshot.be">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="password">PASSWORD</label><br/>
                    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Atleast 8 characters">
                </div>


                <div>
                    <input type="submit" value="LOG IN" class="btn_login">
                </div>


            </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

An extra file I used in **includes/functions.inc.php** to save the functions.

```
<?php
function canilogin( $username, $password){

    $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=snapshot', 'root', 'root');
    $statement = $conn->prepare("select * from users where email = :username");
    $statement->bindValue(':username', 'username');
    $statement->execute();
    $result = $conn->statement($statement);

    if($result->num_rows != 1){
        return false;
    }
        $user = $result->fetch_assoc();
        if(password_verify($password, $user['password'])){
            return true;
        }
    else{
        return false;
    } 
}
?>
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong. The PDO class has no method called `statement`: `$result = $conn->statement($statement);`. It's `$statement->execute();` or one of the `$statement->fetch*()` calls in your case. Here's an example on the [PDOStatement::execute documentation page](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: the class PDO simply doesn't implement a method `statement`

Comment: Also it should be `$statement->bindValue(':username', $username);` else your just checking the string username.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone he's doing a password_verify afterwards

Answer (score 0):

replace the line that contain this code

```
$result = $conn->statement($statement);
```

by

```
if($statement->execute()){
    $user = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // and continue with your code that test the password
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I think he should be replacing at least 2 lines `$statement->execute();
    $result = $conn->statement($statement);`